# PHP changing the value of an svg node

Tags: php, xml, svg

I have a huge svg file(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/273dda3478d676ab1d5d/raw/gistfile1.xml) and I want to change the value of each *. So I need a loop to get through the tspan nodes and gives me the values of it, so I can compare them with a other value and change than the value of the node. I have tried a lot, but nothing worked really good for me. So can anybody of you can help me to get a working loop to change all tspan values?

Comment: There is no way to help you if you do not post your code, your attempts and an explanation what it is that you want to do and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just read the XML and read token after token until you find an open `tspan` Tag? You can manipulate it and save the XML.

http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php